# jQuery: The input element's type does not support selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to send a form via AJAX, using jQuery. But I got the error when clicking the submitting button (it is actually a link, but doen't matter).

That's the error in the console:

```
Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('checkbox') does not support selection.
```

I suspect the problem is that I have some checkboxes there with a multiple selection, and they've been parsed like this:

```
var logo = $('input[name=extra]:checked');
```

I've tried to stringify them, so it looked like: `var logo = JSON.stringify($('input[name=extra]:checked'));` but it didn't seem to fix the problem.

What can be the reason or am I doing something wrong?

UPD: [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4mxsvch3/1/)

Comment: Since you activate the form submission by clicking on a link, I assume that you handle the form submission with javascript... Care to share that piece of code here so we can help you?

Comment: jsfiddle would help here

Comment: You are getting a list of elements, I suspect you want to get their values.

Comment: And that's my [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4mxsvch3/1/)

Comment: `var word1 = $('input[name=line1]:checked').val();`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to get the value with the [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
$('input[name="line1"]:checked').val()
```

I updated your snippet here: http://jsfiddle.net/4mxsvch3/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $('input[name="extra"]').is(":checked");
```

Comment: isn't it just for making sure if the element had been checked?